# How to pass parameters to DbMigration.Sql() Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, syntax, entity-framework-migrations

When using Entity Framework Migrations, the `DbMigration` base class [has a Sql method which takes parameters in an anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.sql%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use it.

```
        Sql(@"
                UPDATE dbo.SlideSets 
                SET Name = @Name, 
            ", false, new {
                Name = "Foo"
            }
        );
```

Results in the error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@Name"
```

What's the correct syntax of this statement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dug into the EF source code and it seems that this parameter (or rather the `MigrationOperation.AnonymousObject` property that's created from it) is not used at all!

[I've created a ticket on their issue tracker to either do something about it or remove the api](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1840)

Comment: I think you're mistaken in your assumption "that takes an anonymous object to pass parameters for a paramterized query". That's not the reason why it's there.

Answer (score 9):

The standard generator for MSSQL is doing nothing with the anonymous object in this case. You need to put the parameter directly into command. Or you can derive your own and handle it.

Comment: What do you mean? the documentation for that parameter explicitly specifies something like `new { SampleArgument = "MyValue" }` is an expected input. I assume it's that the `@Name` portion of the sql string is wrong. Is that not a correct assumption? What is the documentation talking about then?

Comment: The argument is inherited from top class. It can be anything. Every operation can have there something different and also the SQL generator itself is responsible to handle it somehow.

Comment: How does where the parameter is inherited from matter? The question is about what format the sql string should be in for it to work.

Comment: You can vote for support for [Parameterized DbMigration.Sql argument](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5724352-parameterized-dbmigration-sql-argument) on user voice.