# EF 6 Migration: How to execute sql SELECT?

Tags: entity-framework

In our project we have necessity of adding some predefined data to DB. I think the best way and concept is using for that EF Migrations (not Seed method).

But we have a big troubles with adding related data to DB:

For Example:

Suppose we have 2 tables:

*Users*:

- Id (PK auto increment)
- Name
- RoleId

*Roles*:

- Id (PK auto increment)
- Name

Let's suppose that we need to add User(Name = 'John', RoleId = (Id of role that name is 'Admin')).

How can we do it? It would be great if we find a solution that allows us to execute pure SQL SELECT script which not uses Entities of Code First because they can be modified or removed.

For *DELETE*, *INSERT*, *UPDATE* can be used **Sql**(...) method but what about ***SELECT***?

Comment: What do you mean by `not using DbContext`?

Comment: Don’t do something like this:   
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext ())
{
some code

 dbContext.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: using `ADO.NET`? BTW, you don't have to call `SaveChanges()` method after a `SELECT` query.

Comment: It would be great if you provide an example how can I use ADO.NET in migration. But we should keep in mind that connection string should come not from hard coded constant in migration.

Comment: Why can't you use `DbContext`?

Comment: As I understand your point: create DbContext, get connection sting from it, use ADO.NET. Am I correct?

Comment: You can get connection string using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnnStringName"]`. My question is why you can't use DbContext()?

Comment: In my opinion migration process should be independent from dbcontext. It should be like separate module in the system which allow to migrate schema changes and data to db. And as you know we have **Sql** (...) command for _INSERT_, _DELETE_, _UPDATE_ and my question is simple "What about the same command for _SELECT_ statement" ? Using ADO.NET in EF migration is a hack and can be used only if no other ways will be found.

Comment: Well, it's all Entity Framework, so why not use it? If you use a context and the Seed method you can let EF figure out how to insert or update related entities. With SQL scripts you always have capture generated keys yourself.

Comment: For me Seed method is not a place where we can add data to big schema DB. And we need to keep in mind that we can remove and modify entities during development. So using Code First entities with migration process is not a good idea. One of the main ideas of migrations that we can restore any DB state that we want by calling sequence of UP and DOWN methods.

Comment: Update question: restriction: _"do not use DBContext"_ changed to less strict: _"do not use EF Code First Entities"_.

Comment: "not uses Entities of Code First because they can be modified" But that's the whole point of code first + migrations. You alter the entities and migrate the database to match the entities. It's not clear to me why you want to use pure SQL and not the Seed method. "Migration independent from DbContext". It isn't.

Comment: Let's suppose that I have Entity _Home(id, address)_ and added to it few records on Seed method. What will be with Seed method when I remove _Home(id, address)_ Entity(for example client request)?

Comment: You could also ask, what will be the SQL? I really don't see your point. And I don't understand what you mean by "when I remove". When? In the Seed method? While the application is in use? Anyway, if you can do it by SQL you can also do it by `DbSet`/`DbContext` methods, and easier. Try `AddOrUpdate` in SQL.

Comment: Using Code First Entities during migration process is a bad idea. And of course AddOrUpdate method mustn't be used during migrations. Because migration process should be independent. When I drop some entity migrations which are using it should be updated and this is very bad point.

Comment: But in all cases I have a question and it would be great to find an answer on it (not suggestions how question can be changed). If answer is not exists this is result too :)

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have a context into the migration.

Logically first are ran the migrations to Update the DB Schema, then you can have a context to work with the data via it. If your DB does not match the model, or even the table is still not there, you cannot use it in EF.

I had to look into the EF code (and also because was curious). Practically the Sql() method in the DbMigration class in several levels below just adds the SQL string into a list of queries that should be executed into the transaction and moves on. It does not executes it when it is called. So in short EF just fills in a list of codes lines that should be executed in the end at once. And it seems correct if you try to walk in all paths of what you can do with the C# code in the migration code.

The question is quite good actually, unfortunately still I didn't found any better solution rather than using pure ADO.

Another option is to generate more custom SQL queries, and use T-SQL more widely.
For your case as you want to insert the user and set the groupId looking by the name, it can be used with inner select:

```
INSERT INTO Users (Name, GroupId)
VALUES ('John', RoleId = (SELECT Id FROM Roles WHERE Name = 'Admin')).
```

For my issue, I had to a bit do more sophisticated execution - the following does the same as the AddOrUpdate method of the DbSet, using the IF statement:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
    UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

I found it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I'm using good old LINQ for this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    using (var dc = new DbContext("your connection string or name"))
    {
        var ids = dc.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE somefield={0}", 42).ToArray();

        ...
    }
}
```

Using LINQ is better, even for usual migrations, because, there is a bug in DbMigration.Sql method, it ignores arguments: [How to pass parameters to DbMigration.Sql() Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034612/how-to-pass-parameters-to-dbmigration-sql-method)

Comment: Got the error `The model backing the 'MyBDContext' context has changed since the database was created.`

Comment: Please check that you are using Linq database context class "DbContext", from namespace "System.Data.Entity". LINQ can't read EF migrations and it can't throw such exception. Idea of this answer is to use LINQ since it is much more simpler

Comment: There is no LINQ in this answer's code: only SQL. Which is fine: just don't keep calling it LINQ when it's not.