# Entity Framework (EF) migration depending on SQL Server edition

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How to write `DbMigration` using EF 6.x Code-First Migrations that depends on SQL Server edition?

Pseudocode to illustrate:

```
if (SqlEdition == "Enterprise")
{
    Sql(@"...");
}
else
{
    Sql(@"...");
}
```

Comment: Could you use a combination of this query `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')` and run like this to get the edition during migration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30373394/84206

Comment: It throws 'Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.' error even if ONLINE = ON inside 'if' with non-satisfied condition.

Comment: It must be satisfying the condition if the code in the `if` is running, unless it's in the else.  I think you can use Console.Writeline or Debug.Writeline to output messages to the Output window.  Check value of your SqlEdition variable where you are storing the query result and put Writeline's in various places to verify exactly where the code is stepping into each condition.

Comment: It's not possible to refer online indexing in Express edition at all. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458082/sql-server-online-indexing-in-non-enterprise-editions/37458451#37458451

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to accomplish an if conditional within SQL, which certainly won't work as that question demonstrates.  I'm saying do a query just to collect the value of the edition `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')`, store that in a C# variable, then do a C# `if(editionVariable == "Enterprise")` then you can run online indexing statements only in Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach of this answer to run a query during migration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373394/84206

```
using (var dc = new DbContext("your connection string or name"))
{
    string edition = dc.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('edition')").Single();

    if(edition == "Enterprise")
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }

}
```