# SQL Server online indexing in non-enterprise editions

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement the logic depending on SQL Server edition:

```
IF SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 3 /* Enterprise */ OR SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5 /* SQL Azure */
BEGIN
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MobileDeviceId_with_include ON dbo.FineActivations (MobileDeviceId) INCLUDE (ActivationTime, FineId) WITH (ONLINE = ON);
END
```

On SQL Server Express the condition in `IF` is not satisfied. But it still produces the following error:

> Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.

Is it possible to overcome it?

Comment: Are you sure the error message is coming from the code snippet you've posted? Can you check what `SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')` is returning on your instance of SQL Server Express (it should be 4)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to refer Enterprise feature in Express edition, it will not validate syntactically. You can do workaround using Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sqlcmd nvarchar(4000)
SET @sqlcmd = ' CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MobileDeviceId_with_include ON dbo.FineActivations (MobileDeviceId) INCLUDE (ActivationTime, FineId) '

if SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 3 /* Enterprise */ OR SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition') = 5 /* SQL Azure */
begin 
set @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd +'
    with (online = on)'
end
else
begin
set @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + '
    with (fillfactor = 80)'
end

if ((select indexproperty(object_id('FineActivations'),'IX_MobileDeviceId_with_include','IndexID')) is null)
BEGIN
    EXEC (@sqlcmd)
END
```